# Text not filling up paragraph tags on Motorola RAZR and some other devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I'm in the process of rebuilding a very old website, and I've hit a snag.  I have it looking properly on PC browsers, iPhones, iPads, and most Android phones, but on the RAZR and a few other mobile devices, there are paragraphs in which the text only fills the left half.  It's not a mobile-only webpage, but I figured through proper HTML & CSS, it should work as intended on these devices.  I'm not an expert in any way, so any help, advice, or input is appreciated.  Is my CSS causing the trouble?

http://www.sportsmansresource.com/flocalxnewyork_1a.htm

Thanks,

Bruce